# Blender for Previs/Layout

Tags: animation, camera, video-sequence-editor

I'm a professional Previs artist working in Maya and now deciding to give it a try with Blender. I am absolutely new to it...
I couldn't find any chat here related to that (not even tags about it). Is there anybody out there making previs with Blender? Is it possible? Hard/easy? Need much scripting?...
Let me know :)

Cheers everyone!

Comment: Not sure you've heard of it, but I think the new eevee engine might give your work a boost: https://www.blender.org/2-8/

Answer (score 2):

Well, blender.stackexchange focuses around usage oriented questions, specific tasks etc, not opinion based, open questions about the market place.

But the answer is: Yes, there are people doing that. At the Blender Conference 2018 was a talk from someone working at Lucasfilm:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpcKPJTmqSI
(Blender Workflow for Feature Films - Jama Jurabaev)

Grease Pencil is a beast.

https://blenderartists.org/ might be a better place to have a discussion

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! :)
However I'm here exactly for the specific task question of how to make previs using Blender. 
The video is super cool and it does touch some aspects of layout. But I'm looking for something more towards animation...previs...

Comment: There's nothing specific about "Previs in Blender" That's a topic that could and should fill a book. Extremely broad. A specific question in the scope of SE is: How do I make a gold shader or how to rig a knee. Opinion based questions are tricky.